# Derivative of $f(x)=(3x+4)(x-2)^3$

Tags: derivatives

I have the following function:

$$ f(x)=(3x+4)(x-2)^3$$

Now I want the derivative. The book says that it would be:

$$f'(x)=(12x+6)(x-2)^2$$

I just don't understand how they got there. Can anyone enlighten me here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First use the product rule.  Then notice that the two terms you get have a factor in common: $(x-2)^2$.  Then use that fact to **factor** the polynomial.  Then do routine simplifications.

*Factoring* in that way after finding the derivative is the part that students often miss.

Answer (score 3):

You want to first use the product rule: Given a function $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$:

$$f'(x) = g'(x)h(x) + g(x) h'(x)$$

---

We have the following function:

$$f(x) = \underbrace{(3x+4)}_{g(x)}\underbrace{(x-2)^3}_{h(x)}$$
$$g'(x) = 3,\quad h'(x) = 3(x-2)^2$$

$$f'(x) = 3(x-2)^3 + (3x + 4)\cdot 3(x-2)^2$$

Then, factor out the common factor of $(x - 2)^2$:

$$f'(x) = 3(x-2)^3 + (3x + 4)\cdot 3(x-2)^2 = [3(x - 2) + 3(3x + 4)](x-2)^2$$

Simplify the leftmost factor: $$f'(x) = [3(x - 2) + 3(3x + 4)](x-2)^2 = (12x +6)(x-2)^2$$

Comment: Needs another TU cause of the nice brackets +1

Answer (score 1):

First you want to use the product rule.

$f '(x) = (3)(x-2)^3 + (3x+4)(3)(x-2)^2 = (3)(x-2)^3 + (9x+12)(x-2)^2$

Then factor out an $(x-2)^2$:

= $[ 3 (x-2) + (9x + 12) ](x-2)^2 $

= $[ 3x - 6 + 9x + 12 ](x-2)^2 $

= $(12x + 6)(x-2)^2$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can just simplify it to a polynomial using binomial expansions, and then it is trivial.
$$f(x)=(3x+4)(x^3-6x^2+12x-8)$$
$$f(x)=3x^4-14x^3+12x^2+24x-32$$
$$f'(x)=12x^3-42x^2+24x+24$$